# why there is no "Use Core Data" check box with Tabbed Application template

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, tabbed, xcode-template

I need a tabbed application with core data persistence. when i create a new project with Tabbed Application template, i can not find the "Use Core Data" check box. Is it okey to manually add a core data to a project created with Tabbed Application template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not there because there is no standard way to implement core data view controllers in an tabbed application like there is in a table based app.

Yes it is okay to add Core Data to every project you create. You can use a core-data enabled template for reference.

Comment: Can you elaborate further on why there is no standard way to implement core data in view controllers in a tabbed based application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add it yourself. Or you can the empty template and add the tab bar controller yourself.