# Why is Core Data option missing from Tabbed Application?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

If you choose the Tabbed Application application when creating a new Xcode project, Core Data will not be an option.

If I want to use Core Data, is the best route to start with a Single View App, selected Core Data and add the tab bar later?

Comment: I would do what you suggested. You can easily add tab bar controller, while the other route would have you either manually write the core data boilerplate or create a temp project from a template w/core data and copy it over.

Comment: You could do it either way.  It's just as simple to add a Core Data model and proper Core Data stack management classes (such as http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQCoreDataKit/) to a Tabbed Application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why there is no "Use Core Data" check box with Tabbed Applicaion template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902596/why-there-is-no-use-core-data-check-box-with-tabbed-applicaion-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the answer below:

[why there is no "Use Core Data" check box with Tabbed Applicaion template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902596/why-there-is-no-use-core-data-check-box-with-tabbed-applicaion-template)

Also, the way you thought about starting with a Single View Application is true.